# How $log((mn^2)!) = \theta (mn^2 log(mn))$?

Tags: time-complexity

Knowing that $log(n!) = \theta(nlogn)$

Comment: What exactly is the problem? (There is a problem, but can you see it?)

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes was a typo, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\log(mn)\le\color{blue}{\log(mn^2)}\le\log(m^2n^2)=2\log(mn).$$